# How to import dumped Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongorestore

Dumped a MongoDB successfully:

```
$ mongodump -h ourhost.com:portnumber -d db_name01 -u username -p
```

I need to import or export it to a testserver and have struggle with it, please help me figure out.

I tried some ways:

```
$ mongoimport -h host.com:port -c dbname -d dbname_test -u username -p
connected to host.
Password: ...
```

Gives this error:

```
assertion: 9997 auth failed: { errmsg: "auth fails", ok: 0.0 }

$ mongoimport -h host.com:port -d dbname_test -u username -p
```

Gives this error:

```
no collection specified!
```

How to specify which collection to use? What should I use for -d? What I'd like to upload or what I want to use as test out there?  I would like to import the full DB not only  collection of it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The counterpart to `mongodump` is `mongorestore` (and the counterpart to `mongoimport` is `mongoexport`) -- the major difference is in the format of the files created and understood by the tools (`dump` and `restore` read and write [BSON](http://www.bsonspec.org/) files; `export` and `import` deal with text file formats: JSON, CSV, TSV.

If you've already run `mongodump`, you should have a directory named `dump`, with a subdirectory for each database that was dumped, and a file in those directories for each collection. You can then restore this with a command like:

```
mongorestore -h host.com:port -d dbname_test -u username -p password dump/dbname/
```

Assuming that you want to put the contents of the database `dbname` into a new database called `dbname_test`.

Comment: also see next answer: `--authenticationDatabase admin` did the trick for me.

Comment: you might also need the archive param if it is gziped `mongorestore --db database --drop --gzip --archive=archive.tar.gz`

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else might reach this question after all these years (like I did), and if you are using

- a dump which was created using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongodump)
- and trying to restore from a `dump` directory
- and going to be using the default port `27017`

All you got to do is,

```sh
mongorestore dump/
```

Refer to the [mongorestore doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#syntax) for more info. cheers!

Answer (score 7):

You may have to specify the authentication database

```
mongoimport -h localhost:27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u user -p -d database -c collection --type csv --headerline --file awesomedata.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

When you do a `mongodump` it will dump in a binary format.  You need to use `mongorestore` to "import" this data.

`Mongoimport` is for importing data that was exported using `mongoexport`